tcolorbox: align baselines with side by side
According to the tcolorbox documentation, the key sidebyside align=top aligns the baseline of the left-handed and right-handed side of a tcolorbox.
But with
\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside, sidebyside align=top, sidebyside gap=0pt, size=minimal]
  A\hrulefill
  \tcblower
  a\hrulefill\par
  a\hrulefill
\end{tcolorbox}

the baseline are not aligned:

Another example, with an image:

which is what I expect with sidebyside align=top seam, not sidebyside align=top.
What am I missing ?
Example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside, sidebyside align=top, sidebyside gap=0pt, size=minimal]
  A\hrulefill
  \tcblower
  a\hrulefill\par
  a\hrulefill
\end{tcolorbox}


\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside, sidebyside align=top, sidebyside gap=0pt, size=minimal]
  \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}\hrulefill
  \tcblower
  A\hrulefill\par
  A\hrulefill\par
  A\hrulefill\par
  A\hrulefill
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}


there is a color whatsit and so the top alignment point is above the letters. You could use a \strut on both side to force the same line height.

@UlrikeFischer It is the same with blankest (no color, no frame). I can use \strut, but this will not work with an image, or if I use different font sizes for the two sides.

try with lualatex and \usepackage{luacolor}. This doesn't insert color whatsits. Then you can see that this matters. You could make a bug report, perhaps the author can avoid the color there (but generally this is hard).

As a workaround, you could use two minipages instead of the sidebyside option

@UlrikeFischer It works as expected when I add luacolor. Thanks.

Reported: https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/302

@mbert Thank you very much. I should have done it, but I never took the time.
